# Oracle Moving Average without Current Row

Tags: oracle, plsql

Would like to calculate moving average in oracle for the last 30 records excluding current row.

```
select crd_nb, flng_month, curr_0380,
avg(curr_0380) over (partition by crd_nb order by flng_month ROWS 30 PRECEDING) mavg
from us_ordered
```

The above SQL calculates moving average for 30 records including current row.

Is there any way to calculate moving average excluding current row.?

Comment: rows between 30 preceding and 1 preceding?

Comment: wow...wow...wow... @"be here now", You the man!. You nailed it. Please post your comment as answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
  crd_nb, 
  flng_month, 
  curr_0380,
  avg(curr_0380) over (
    partition by crd_nb 
    order by flng_month 
    ROWS between 30 PRECEDING and 1 preceding
  ) mavg
from us_ordered
```

Answer (score 1):

@be_here_now's answer is clearly superior. I'm leaving mine in place nonetheless, as it's still functional, if needlessly complex.

---

An answer would to be to get the `sum` and `count` individually, subtract out the current row then divide the two results. It's a little ugly, but it should work:

```
SELECT crd_nb,
       flng_month,
       curr_0380,
         (  SUM (curr_0380)
            OVER (PARTITION BY crd_nb 
                  ORDER BY flng_month ROWS 30 PRECEDING)
          - curr_0380)
       / (  COUNT (curr_0380)
            OVER (PARTITION BY crd_nb 
                  ORDER BY flng_month ROWS 30 PRECEDING)
          - 1)
          mavg
FROM   us_ordered
```

If `curr_0380` can be `null`, you'd have to tweak this slightly so that the current row is removed only if it's `not null`.